# Why I am getting results in my query even when I don't have value 0 for email adrees in my column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
MariaDB [db]> SELECT * from jobseeker_account WHERE email_address = 0;
+----+----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+
| id | jobseeker_code | email_address                  | email_token                              | code_token | email_verify | password                                                     | google_id | facebook_id | date_created        | last_login          | last_change_pass | status |
+----+----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+
|  1 | APP052000001   | user@gmail.com          | 4d517de609a97afae45aee04d4862e8a7c195805 | 678503     |            0 | $2y$10$0Ug1iGPsBqoy5p7YjwOx3uQwQLM6S5hyYy8e2QX9yYwlqsNNnoHJS | NULL      | NULL        | 2020-05-14 16:25:50 | 2020-05-14 16:25:50 | NULL             |      1 |
|  2 | APP052000002   | user@gmail1.com | f5ce9b3b545019c71a0846e13c10a1c8a5edb3bd | 397097     |            0 | $2y$10$CGXrDVMUKrtreLgQ0gkEp.UNBa8ogtJ6SWhxPjUQEQ7a1GxhPBg1W | NULL      | NULL        | 2020-05-14 19:36:31 | 2020-05-14 19:36:31 | NULL             |      1 |
+----+----------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+--------+
2 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.001 sec)
```

I am getting result even when I don't have 0 value in email address column

Comment: `show warnings`

Comment: MariaDB [db]> SHOW WARNINGS
    -> ;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                          |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'APP052000001' |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'APP052000002' |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

Comment: you can edit the question to include information. Your email address is being converted to a double, which match `= 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this condition:

```
email_address = 0
```

is evaluated, what happens is an implicit conversion of email to an integer so that both parts of the equality have the same data type.
The result of the conversion of a value like `user@gmail.com` which can't be converted to an integer is `0`.
So the condition returns `TRUE` for such values of the email.
If there is an email like `123user@gmail.com` this would be converted to `123` and you would not get it in the results.
Everything about type conversion in expressions is explained here: 
[Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)

Comment: so i need to add "0" to my query? like this SELECT * from jobseeker_account WHERE email_address = "0";

Comment: Exactly, so it will be a string comparison, but it's a good practice to use single quotes: `WHERE email_address = '0'` because double quotes can also be used for identifiers.